# spring boot maven compile package not exists

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

In A module there's a service (in package `nfts.core`), and B module contains a implementation for the service in A. The development kit i choose idea. I have imported A into B project by importing modules in project structure.In addition, pom dependency is done.

When I use spring boot parent 1.3.7 version , `mvn clean install A` and `mvn clean install B`, then it succeeds.

There is a log may be useful:

`[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ core ---`

However, when I use spring boot 2.0.4 version, then come out package nfts.core not exists.

`[INFO]--- maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0:compile (default-compile) @ core ---`

Why? Can I customize the maven plugin for spring boot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds more like you are experiencing a maven issue than a Spring Boot one.

I'm guessing that you're just trying to do a build based on something that doesn't exist in your local repository yet in the new case.

**I'd try:**

- Make sure that if you use "mvn clean install -U" on the 1.3.7 version it still builds.  The -U will make maven forcibly update its indices.
- Possibly try removing the libraries altogether from your .m2 repository folder and then re-building (the 1.3.7 version).
- If your old version still works after that and your new version doesn't, we'll probably need more information (e.g. your POM).

Comment: Thanks for your help ! The problem perplex me 2 days. Some one told me that , spring boot change the structure of the packages when the spring boot maven plugin build my project A. So, B project can not read the package exactly from the jar

Comment: @Glaha - Are things working now?  Generally, if you're updating to Spring Boot 2 and you have multiple modules using it, you should rebuild each one individually with the same Spring Boot version to avoid issues :).  I'd also bump up the version of your modules just so you can tell the difference and make sure you're not including the old ones built with the other version of boot.

Comment: I delete the spring boot maven plugin in A project and maven clean install . It worked . Now , I can use A in B project.  Spring boot changed the structure of package since version 1.4.0.

Comment: @Glaha - Cool; that's good to know.  I recommend you post and accept your own solution since you figured it out :).  Its nice to close out the questions properly for other people.  I'm not sure if you have the rights for that since you're a new user; if you don't let me know and I'll just post one for you to accept.  I recall a few things are pretty restricted at first :).

Comment: Rights?I don't know how to do. I have tried. May be I didn't get what you said.My english is poor.

Comment: I just meant post your own solution to the question and accept it to close the question out :).  You know... click "Add another answer", your own answer, and then click the green check-mark! =)